# Partially obscured from view(formal)

Tags: single-word-requests

Good day all,

As the title suggests, I am looking for a formal word that means "partially obscured from view" meaning part of the object is visible, while part of it is not. Words such as nestled, sunken, semi-visible, semi-hidden ect... are inappropriate for the context of usage. Nestled and sunken suggest a physical relationship to the object that is obscuring(touching, connected), and semi- is not professional.

Thank you.

Comment: 'Partially hidden' is not informal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of performance venues -- theatres and stadiums and such -- sell "*[obstructed view](http://help.ticketmaster.com/what-does-obstructed-view-mean/)*" seats for a lower price.  Those seats have something (column or the like) blocking the view, at least partially.  Perhaps ***obstructed*** would work for you?

> ***[Obstructed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obstruct)***
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1 Block (an opening, path, road, etc.); be or get in the way of.
>
> ‘she was obstructing the entrance’

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! This one fits the billet perfectly.

Comment: @LanetRino Note that if you like the answer, you can upvote it as well as accepting it. (You can also upvote any other answers that you like, even if they aren't *quite* what you were looking for.)

Answer (score 2):

Some words like *veiled* or *shadowed* would probably work, but I think you're looking for the word *eclipsed*.

Comment: Quote relevant definitions from reliable dictionaries for the words you suggest.

Comment: See also: _[What good reference works on English are available?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573)_

Comment: I think eclipsed is probably the best candidate so far. Thank you. Not ready to mark it the answer yet though.

Comment: Something can be _eclipsed_ partially or fully. It still works as _partially eclipsed_ (not a single word though).

Answer (score 2):

In fact, ***obscured*** (used in your very question) serves your purpose, unless you don't consider it *formal* enough. See the examples below too and you will see what I mean.

Collins:

> **[obscure](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/obscure)**
>   **3**. *verb*
>
> **If one thing obscures another, it prevents it from
>   being seen** or heard **properly**.
>
> Trees obscured his vision; he couldn't see much of the Square's
>   southern half.
>
> One wall of the parliament building is now almost completely obscured
>   by a huge banner.

Comment: obscured does not suggest "partially", it suggest completely covered.

Comment: Just use partially obscured Lanet, I been thinking about this the last hour too and trying to zen this to one word hurts my brain.

Comment: @LanetRino, I beg to differ; _obscured_ does __not__ imply _completely covered_. The dictionary examples are proof enough, don't you think? In fact, the second example uses _completely_ to qualify _obscured_. I can still understand if you do not _prefer_ to use it, though.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I did not mean to give you a headache!

Comment: @LanetRino no you didn't give me a headache! Just trying to help. Hope you find your word!

Answer (score 0):

What I think of that may work:

1. Indistinctly
2. Vaguely

Adding the 'ly' makes it take on more of the word "partial".

Answer (score 0):

While there are other good answers to this question, word choice is often about what other "baggage" or flavors a word brings along with it

I might suggest Eclipse be used in some situations

> ***eclipse*** from [Oxford living dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eclipse)
>   NOUN
>
> 1 An obscuring of the light from one celestial body by the passage of another between it and the observer or between it and its source of illumination.
>
> ‘an eclipse of the sun’
>
> 1.1 A loss of significance or power in relation to another person or thing.
>
> *‘the election result marked the eclipse of the traditional right’*
>
> ***Eclipse*** VERB [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1(of a celestial body) obscure the light from or to (another celestial body)
>   ‘Jupiter was eclipsed by the Moon’
>   More example sentences
>
> 1.1 Deprive (someone or something) of significance or power.
>
> *‘the economy has eclipsed the environment as the main issue’*
>
> **1.2 literary use of eclipse**
>
> *Obscure or block out (light)*
>
> ‘a sea of blue sky violently eclipsed by showers’